# How to suggest the right question for the duplicate flag

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

If a question is very common, how should we identify the best question to suggest in the duplicate flag?

There is a very common example on StackOverflow regarding javascript web developlment. Some one asks how to make cross domain ajax requests in a page.
The very common answer is: you can't, but there are a bunch of hacks to circumvent the issue.

In this case, however, there is great [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) that exposes the problem and explores the solutions.

In all other cases, where no explicit wiki is available, how can we identify the right duplicate?

Comment: You should choose the post with the highest score and best explanations...

Comment: Try searching using google instead. The page rank they apply helps in finding the most popular one, sometimes.

Comment: Usually I look for the oldest post, assuming it's not too crappy.